# Reference a range to a cell value

Tags: excel, vba

A better way to put it:

1. I have many dataframes of variable column length, so xmax_pos = col_length.
2. I want to apply a formula using this col_length as a range for each dataframe; if my range is bigger than my df, the formula won't work.

```
=formula(A1:A"xmax_pos")
```

Is there a way for me to assign a range indirectly? Without manually modifying the range.

Comment: Probably using `INDEX`: `A1:INDEX(A:A,"xmax_pos")` where `xmax_pos` is a number or formula that evaluates to a number.

Comment: @BigBen I tried it but it didn't work. Something about adding a formula inside a range Excel doesn't like it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also create a dynamic named range:

```
=$A$2:INDEX($A:$A,COUNTA($A:$A)))
```

See https://exceljet.net/formula/dynamic-named-range-with-index
As @BigBen suggested, it's better than using OFFSET

Comment: @BigBen I like those dynamic named ranges, so I updated my reply with your remark.

Comment: Good find from ExcelJet for sure! Haven't seen that link yet. Learned this trick from Scott Craner I think, here on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and you are quite close. Simply build a string and use that in an "indirect" function.

For example:

```
=indirect("A1")
```

...will return the value in cell A1.

In your specific case, you would build the range reference like: "A1:A" & xmax_pos

I can't be more specific than that due to lack of specifics in your question.

Comment: `INDIRECT` is volatile and should be avoided when possible. Something like `A1:INDEX(A:A,10)` is much better.

Comment: Careful: INDIRECT is a volatile function. This has a few implication, including performance (for large sheets with lots of formula), and the fact that a workbook gets 'dirty' every time you open it.

Comment: @BigBen, if you try that suggestion you'll see that it needs editing.

Comment: But it actually does work, right? https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKRu7.png , or https://i.stack.imgur.com/gALbl.png Not sure what you're trying to get at.

Comment: That depends on if the spillover is acceptable, I guess.

Comment: Also added a `SUM` example, passing `A1:INDEX(A:A,10)` to `SUM` or another function works perfectly fine.

Comment: Yes, that does it.

Comment: It does work, my bad! Does it allow to grab two columns?

Comment: Sure, change `A:A` to `B:B`.